# @Autowire on field vs @Autowired on Construcor

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired, constructor-injection

I am developing a SpringBoot application. Can anyone help me understand what is the difference between the below piece of code. I am working on a restful service and I saw constructor being autowired. I can understand its Constructor Injection. Usually I autowire a field. So I am unable to understand the difference between two.

**Scenario 1:**

```
 @RestController
 public class SomeServiceController {

 @Autowired 
 private ASerice aService;

 @Autowired
 private BService bService;
}
```

**Scenario 2:**

```
 @RestController
 public class SomeServiceController {

 private ASerice aService;

 private BService bService;

 @Autowired
 public SomeServiceController (AService aService, BService bService)
 {
   this.aService = aService;
   this.bService = bService;

 }
}
```

Comment: Constructor-based injection allows immutability by `final`-ising the fields being set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that with the constructor injection, the class SomeServiceController can only be created if with this constructor.

So you could even instantiate the class to test it.

With field injection, this is not possible. To instantiate the class for a test, you must use reflection to set the two private services.

It's highly recommended to use constructor expression.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-collaborators

Comment: Thanks Simon for quick reply.
I have 2c doubts:
1. You mean to say that in order to test without ConstructorInjection I will have to mock 
    AService and BService. If I use Scenario 2 I need not do this...
2. If we do ConstructorInjection, I will have to add class in the 
 Constructor everytime I add a new dependency.

Comment: Yes both is true. The Spring team recommends using constructor injection as well. Please read this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-collaborators